# Android - How to use a float from an activity in a running service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I have created a *float* variable in an *Activity*.

I have a *GPSService* running in the background, and I would like to modify the GPS updating rate according to the *float* variable defined in the *Activity*.

How can I save the value of the *float*, and use it in the *GPSService*, even if the *Activity* has been killed?

Thank you!

Comment: Declare float variable as static

Comment: Do not use static, because the activity cannot be initialized in order to retrieve, you can use shared preferences to save that value and get it whenever you want. Or you can be overkill and make a variable initialization in your application and set it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) to save your data to local storage of app and fetch it anywhere in the app.

Comment: So, I wrote this code in my *Activity*: 
`    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putFloat("gps_rate", gpsRefreshRate);
        editor.commit();
`

And this in the GPS Service:
`    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = sharedpreferences.getFloat(gps_rate, 5000);`

But Android Studio tells me he doesn't know sharedpreferences in the Service. What can I do to share sharedpreferences?

Comment: So did you succeed or not?

Comment: No, because the Service can't resolve the symbol "sharedpreferences"

Comment: Do not declare this variable globally then. Use the same code to get the sharepreferences like : SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = sharedpreferences.getFloat(gps_rate, 5000);